# Is there a way to get the name of the top level PHP file from inside an included one?

Tags: php

Let's say I'm writing a global logData method that wants to write to a log file that has the same name as the php that's running it, but with a .log extension.

I'm including this logging in a parent php with the intention of having it always write to log files that are whatever the *parent file name is (not the tools.php lib in which it's sitting).

So, I have 
/some/arbitrary/directory/parent.php

which calls

include ("/path/to/my/php/libs/tools.php");

but when I run my logging method that's in tools.php it logs to a file called

/path/to/my/php/libs/tools.php.log

rather than 
/some/arbitrary/directory/parent.php.log  (which is what I'd like).

I'm using `__FILE__` which is behaving this way (probably as its intended to).  Is there a command for getting the parent's file name so that I can get this to work as I intend? Or will I have to pass **FILE** as a param into my method from the parent php to get it to write to the correct output file?

TIA

Comment: I don't think this is possible. However, you could always pass the value of `__FILE__` to the global method in the parent script as a parameter. (Saw your edit too late)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably use $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]

Answer (score 2):

debug_backtrace() will give you what you need.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `__FILE__` to the log class.

Something like:

```
// file:/some/arbitrary/directory/parent.php
$logger = new Logger(__FILE__);


// file:/path/to/my/php/libs/tools.ph
public function __construct($file) {
  // But it is not good idea to save log file same with php files.
  $this->log_path = $file.'.log';
}
```